# Preventing to using different sessiosn files for same user, from several different browser

Tags: php, session

In my php application, I plan do something like this: When user log on, save his `session_id` in database.

and then, every time at log on, check, if this user already have old session id, then do :

```
session_destroy();
session_id('old_session_id_here');
session_start();
```

I want this for preventing, that  same user uses different sessions, when this user is logged on site, same time, with different browsers.

So is this good practice?  may cause this any problems?

Comment: What's your Logout user scenario. did you remove variable from database ?

Comment: @TarangP - Yes, `session_destroy();` in PHP and remove variable from database.

Comment: `on different browsers`, this can't be done. In order to be able to do this you would need to be able to identify a computer as `unqiue` e.g. `IP address`, `browsers' fingerprint`, `..`. There is no possible way you could do this with `PHP` for several browsers as `ip's` can be shared and the fingerprint surely would be different no doubt that.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. You are first going to start a "temporary" session in order to retrieve the old `session_id`, then it's possible yes.

Comment: @DarkBee - it's possible yes, question is how safe it is? may cause this any problems? (which  I don't see right now).

Comment: hmm.. I think I should not remove variable from database at Logout

Comment: Well.. If you're database is compromised, the attacker could be able to spoof the `session`'s at that point. But other than that I don't see any issues. It could be useful when you have a webshop with a cart and you add some item's in your cart at work, you come home and you login and your cart is back...